# Firebase Cloud Messaging: ServiceIntent not found for specific manufacturers

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have developed an Android chat app that has successfully been receiving FCM push notifications on most Android devices. However, we found that on certain devices such as {OPPO, VIVO, Xiomi, Asus}. we are unable to start our service when an FCM message is sent.

We searched through the logs and found:

> 2019-03-14 16:23:50.191 29074-29074/com.ourapp E/FirebaseInstanceId:
>   Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

Our project is structured as follows:

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.FirebaseScheduledJobService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Project Level Gradle File:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    ...
}
```

Firebase Job Scheduler Service:

```
    public class FirebaseScheduledJobService extends JobService {
        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                if (job.getExtras() != null)
                    sendDeliveryReceipt(job.getExtras());
                jobFinished(job, false);
            }).start();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
            return false;
        }

        private void sendDeliveryReceipt(Bundle bundle) {
            String currentUserJid = SharedPreferenceManager.instance.getUserJidFromPreference();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

We have researched this issue and found that we need to manually enable auto-start for those manufacturers and also have the user turn off battery optimisations for our app. However, we think that this solution is too technical for normal users because they are largely unaware of such settings.

To help, we have added device specific code to help the user navigate to the auto-start settings page on their device. We also added code to help those users open their battery optimisation settings.

Is there any other way to solve this FCM problem for these specific manufacturers?

It may be worth noting that our research also led us the conclude that certain popular apps are white-listed by default. Of course this does not help us,
but may help explain why other popular apps do not require such measures.

We would be grateful for any assistance. Thank you.